# Contain Element Inside a Button

Tags: javascript, css

In my React project, I have a ball following the cursor using Javascript and having it only appear when it hovers over a button element using this css block:

```
#app button:hover + .ball {
  display: block;
}

.ball {
  display: none;
}
```

It currently works, however I'm trying to figure out a way to have the ball contained inside the button. Right now, if you hover over the edge of the button, the ball extends outside the button.

[Project codepen](https://codepen.io/ericnguyen23/pen/MWwzXOX)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I would suggest looking into using a wrapper element and CSS overflow styling.

Comment: See how I posted your `codepen` into an embedded code snippet in my answer as an example of how to include MVEs mentioned by Quentin into stack overflow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `button` and the `.ball` elements within a container div of some sort then you can make `overflow:hidden` on the container:

**Within `render`:**

```
<div className="button-container">
  <button>BUTTON</button>
  <div ref={ballRef} className="ball"></div>
</div>
```

**In stylesheet:**

```
.button-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
let mouseX = 0
let mouseY = 0
let ballX = 0
let ballY = 0
let speed = 0.2

const Page = () => {
  const ballRef = React.useRef(null)
  const animate = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (ballRef && ballRef.current) {
      let distX = mouseX - ballX
      let distY = mouseY - ballY
      ballX = ballX + distX * speed
      ballY = ballY + distY * speed
      ballRef.current.style.left = ballX + "px"
      ballRef.current.style.top = ballY + "px"
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  }, [ballRef, mouseX, mouseY, ballX, ballY])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onMouseMove = event => {
      mouseX = event.pageX
      mouseY = event.pageY
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)

    animate()

    return () => document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove)
  }, [])  

 return (
   <React.Fragment>
     <div className="button-container">
       <button>BUTTON</button>
       <div ref={ballRef} className="ball"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="divs"></div>
     <div class="divs"></div>
   </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
#app button:hover + .ball {
  display: block;
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ball {
  display: none;
}

button{
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
}

.ball {
  background-color: red;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  transition: transform 0.4s, border 0.4s;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.divs{
  background-color: gray;
  padding:20px;
  margin:20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```